# Преобразование местного времени в UTC

Tags: c#

Почему эта строка даёт мне локальное время с компьютера?

```
System.DateTime.SpecifyKind(System.DateTime.Now, System.DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString();
```

Comment: В каком смысле? Вы же первым параметром передаете System.DateTime.Now, что означает возьми время с ПК.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var currentTimeInUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;`

или

`var currentTimeInUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now);`

Answer (score 0):

Метод **SpecifyKind**, под капотом не производит никакого конвертирования (к/от UTC) с переданной ему датой. Фактически там происходит следующее:

```
return new DateTime(value.InternalTicks, kind);
```

Таким образом просто меняется признак к какому часовому поясу относится значение даты(либо ни к какому в случае **Unspecified**)

Как уже сказано в ответе, конвертирование происходит при вызове

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc
```

Есть более короткие записи:

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()
```

Если интересно понять как преобразования работают внутри, смотрите класс TimeZoneInfo и его методы:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc()
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc()
```